# exportar datatable para pdf , excel

Tags: jquery-datatables

Ando a tentar usar o tabletools para exportar o datatables mas não me esta a aparecer os botões.

tenho os seguinte

```js
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../TableTools-2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
```

podem ajudar-me.

Answer (score 1):

resolvido

```js
  "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
         "aButtons": [                
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Exportar",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf", "print"],
                    // TODO: Get this working.
                    "fnCellRender": function ( sValue) {                     
                        return sValue + " TableTools";
                    }
                }
            ],
            "sSwfPath": "../swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
```